# Change color of text inside a calendardate in a better way

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

I have code to change color of a string in a specific calendar day.

However, it seams like a 'code smell' to have html code in my back-end c# code:

```
            if (CabinTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataSet1.SummerCabinRow item in CabinTable.Rows)
                {
                    if (e.Day.Date >= item.StartDate && e.Day.Date <= item.EndDate)
                    {
                        e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
                        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0xFF8F8F);

                        //Here I want to create a more professional code if its possible!!
                        string color = GetColor(item);
                        string bookerName = "<div style=\"color:" + color + "\">" + item["Customer"] + "</div>";
                        e.Cell.Text = e.Day.Date.Day.ToString() + "<br/>" + bookerName;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

//Get the users unique color that comes from my database 
private string GetColor(DataSet1.SummerCabinRow item)
        {
            DataSet1.CustomerDataTable CustomerTable = new DataSet1TableAdapters.CustomerTableAdapter().GetData();
            DataSet1.CustomerRow currentUser = CustomerTable.Where(user => user.Name.Equals(item["Customer"])).FirstOrDefault();
            return currentUser.Color;
        }
```

Is there a more appropriate way to set the Text color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cell should be a `WebControl` which means it has a `CssClass` property.  You can set that property and then add the appropriate css rule in your css file:

```
e.Cell.CssClass = color;
```

and then in your css:

```
.green{
   color: green;
}
```